# compare 2 sheets deleting all non matches no case sensitive

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba that compare 2 sheets and outputs unique names to a userform, how do to i make the compare non case sensitive. Also is there a way to only compare up to the first character in each cell. ie a hyphon.

```
Sub unknownservers()
    Dim iListCount As Integer
    Dim iCtr As Integer

    ' compare serverlist against daily report for unknown servers
    ' within a userform with a send email option

    ' Turn off screen updating to speed up macro.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Get count of records to search through (list that will be deleted).
    iListCount = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through the "master" list.
    For Each x In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        ' Loop through all records in the second list.
        For iCtr = iListCount To 1 Step -1
            ' Do comparison of next record.
            ' To specify a different column, change 1 to the column number.
            If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then
                ' If match is true then delete row.
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next iCtr
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value > "" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next r

    'display unknown servers on a user form with a choice to send in an email
    frmunknownservers.Textunknownservers.Text = msg
    frmunknownservers.Show

    'MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly, "Unknown servers"
End Sub
```

Comment: does your values `x.Value` and `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value` always contain hyphen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** max value of `Integer` is only `32768`. That's why I've changed

```
Dim iListCount As Integer
Dim iCtr As Integer
```

to

```
Dim iListCount As Long
Dim iCtr As Long
```

**2)** deleting rows in loop may be very slow. I've slightly modified your code to avoid it.

**New code:**

```
Sub unknownservers()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rngToDel As Range, x As Range
    Dim iListCount As Long, iCtr As Long
    Dim firstHyp1 As Integer, firstHyp2 As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    iListCount = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each x In ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        For iCtr = 1 To iListCount
            firstHyp1 = InStr(1, x.Value, "-")
            firstHyp2 = InStr(1, ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Value, "-")
            firstHyp1 = IIf(firstHyp1 = 0, Len(x.Value), firstHyp1 - 1)
            firstHyp2 = IIf(firstHyp2 = 0, Len(ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Value), firstHyp2 - 1)

            If UCase(Left(ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Value, firstHyp2)) = UCase(Left(x.Value, firstHyp1)) Then
                If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDel = ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1)
                Else
                    Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next iCtr
    Next

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value > "" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next r

    frmunknownservers.Textunknownservers.Text = msg
    frmunknownservers.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, the code works but if for example JAMES is on sheet1 and james-senior is on sheet2 this is a match so should be deleted as should banana and BANANA be classed as a match. i should have been clearer not all names in a list will have hyphons in them, but if they do as long as up to the first hyphon matches that is classed as a match. so should be deleted

Comment: my answer was based on your comment `yes always a hyphon`. But, ok, try updated answer